# странности в работе с пхп, всгда error

Tags: php

/captcha/index.php

```
session_start();
$randomnr = mt_rand(1000,9999);
$_SESSION['randomnr2'] = md5($randomnr);
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 125 , 125, 125);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 70, $black);
$font = 'Arial.ttf';
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, 10, 38, $white, $font, $randomnr);
header("Expires: Wed, 1 Jan 1997 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

header ("Content-type: image/gif");
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

/reg.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password2']) && !empty($_POST['code'])) {
$code = (int) $_POST['code'];

//проверки разные
if (md5($code) != $_SESSION['randomnr2'])   { 
echo 'ошибка';
exit;}
//все ок, пишем в бау
}
```

html часть reg.php

```
<form action="?" method="POST">

<div class="col-4 col-12-xsmall">
<img src="/captcha/index.php" />
</div>
<div class="col-8 col-12-xsmall">
<input name="code" type="text" placeholder="код с картинки">
</div>
<div class="col-12">
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="вперед" class="primary" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</form>
```

всегда выдает, что код не верен.
что не так у меня?
OpenServer посл.версии.

Comment: Что за ошибка то?

Comment: Откуда взялся `$code`?

Comment: А кто сессию открывать будет? `session_start();`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в начале /reg.php написать `session_start();`